# MySQL create view as join of other views, how to avoid typing all the column names?

Tags: mysql

In order to create a view as a join of two other views I'll do the following:

```
CREATE VIEW view_join AS SELECT
    a.id,
    a.time,

    a.column1,
    a.column2,
    a.column3,

    b.column1,
    b.column2,
    b.column3  
FROM view_one a INNER JOIN view_two b 
WHERE a.id = b.id;
```

Both origin views have `id` and `time` and want them in the `view_join`, for all the other columns I want everything. My lazy side is telling must be a way to avoid typing all the column names, is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In views, I think it is best to include the column names explicitly.  That makes it obvious where they come from.

If the *only* common column between the two was the `id` column you could do:

```
CREATE VIEW view_join AS
    SELECT *
    FROM view_one a INNER JOIN
         view_two b 
         USING (id);
```

But that won't work in your case because the result would have two columns named `time`.  Another is to take the columns from one table:

```
CREATE VIEW view_join AS
    SELECT a.*
           b.column1,
           b.column2,
           b.column3  
    FROM view_one a INNER JOIN
         view_two b 
         ON a.id = b.id;
```

But I would still recommend that you list all the columns individually.

Comment: Would some one consider repeating columns (in both origin views, `id` and `time`) a (bad smell) design issue?

Comment: @KcFnMi . . . Bad idea.  You may get an error when you try to query it, or accessing the column will return an indeterminate value.

Comment: At least removing `time` from i.e. `view_two` would allow the quick approach presented in the answer. Not sure if I complete got you comment.